# Line numbers not updating on 2nd monitor - Eclipse STS 2.8.1RELEASE - OS X Lion

Tags: eclipse, osx-lion, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, line-numbers

I'm currently developing on a Macbook Pro running Lion, and I'm having an issue where line numbers (and all other features that are on that panel including breakpoints, section hiding/expanding, etc) don't scroll with the source code in the editor.

I found this filed bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294929), but what I need to do to fix this isn't clear. I'm hoping to avoid a re-install and re-import of all my projects and other plug-ins.

Thoughts? Is it an STS issue (not really sure what version of Eclipse STS relates to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make this clearer, my "solution" was to change display settings so that my 2nd monitor  was my main one.

If somebody comes up with a better solution, I'll un-check this and check the new response.

Answer (score 1):

Check what version of Eclipse you are running off of.  Did you install STS from the installer or the zip?  Or did you start with a vanilla eclipse and use the update sites?

This problem happened with Eclipse 3.7.0 and Lion.  This was a bug in SWT, but I believe that it is fixed in 3.7.1.

To find the Eclipse version click on :
 STS -> about STS -> Installation details -> plugins -> org.eclipse.swt.

It should be 3.7.0 or 3.7.1 or 3.7.2.  If it is 3.7.0, then you should update to 3.7.2 (released last week).

Comment: Hmm... Version is 3.7.1.v3738a. Pretty sure I installed from the STS installer. I did NOT start with vanilla eclipse.

Comment: Oh well.  All I can say is that I used to have this problem, but then it went away.  I can't quite remember what I did to fix it.  This is definitely an Eclipse Platform issue, not an STS issue.  I'd also recommend making sure you are running the latest patch of Max OSX.

Comment: Oh...one thing I do remember is that resizing the window, even just a little fixes the problem temporarily.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I feel like if I re-installed, it'd probably be fixed. Don't really want to go through the whole process of re-installing and re-importing and re-installing other plugins. I just switched the main monitor to be the bigger one (where I usually have STS). Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: I'm also having the same issue with STS 2.9.0 on Lion on the 2nd monitor.  Using the main monitor is a good tip.